# Relative C code execution time analysis using system monotonic clock

Tags: c, linux, macos, profiling, clock

Is there is a simple but sure way to measure the relative differences in performance between two algorithm implementations in C programs. More specifically, I want to compare the performance of implementation A vs. B? I'm thinking of a scheme like this:

- In a unit test program:

  1. start timer
  2. call function
  3. stop timer
  4. get difference between start stop time
- Run the scheme above for a pair of functions A and B, then get a percentage difference in execution time to determine which is faster.

Upon doing some research I came across this question about using a [Monotonic clock on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680461/monotonic-clock-on-osx) in C, which apparently can give me at least nanosecond precision. To be clear, I understand that precise, controlled measurements are hard to perform, like what's discussed in ["With O(N) known and system clock known, can we calculate the execution time of the code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40600683), which I assume should be irrelevant in this case because I only want a relative measurement.

Everything considered, is this a sufficient and valid approach towards the kind of analysis I want to perform? Are there any details or considerations I might be missing?

Comment: If you're working on macOS Sierra (10.12) or later, then there is finally support for `clock_gettime()` provided by the system, though the real resolution is only microseconds, not nanoseconds. (That is, the `tv_nsec` component of the answer from `clock_gettime()` always ends with three zeros.)  The question you reference pre-dates Sierra by over four years.

Comment: Well I'm working with 10.11 and the mach header function calls from the reference still work. But This is good to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main modification I make to the timing scheme you outline is to ensure that the same timing code is used for both functions — assuming they do have an identical interface, by passing a function pointer to skeletal code.

As an example, I have some code that times some functions that validate whether a given number is prime.  The control function is:

```
static void test_primality_tester(const char *tag, int seed, int (*prime)(unsigned), int count)
{
    srand(seed);
    Clock clk;
    int nprimes = 0;
    clk_init(&clk);

    clk_start(&clk);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (prime(rand()))
            nprimes++;
    }
    clk_stop(&clk);

    char buffer[32];
    printf("%9s: %d primes found (out of %d) in %s s\n", tag, nprimes,
           count, clk_elapsed_us(&clk, buffer, sizeof(buffer)));
}
```

I'm well aware of [`srand()` — why call it once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once/), but the point of using `srand()` once each time this function is called is to ensure that the tests process the same sequence of random numbers.  On macOS, `RAND_MAX` is `0x7FFFFFFF`.

The type `Clock` contain analogues to two `struct timespec` structures, for the start and stop time.  The `clk_init()` function initializes the structure; `clk_start()` records the start time in the structure; `clk_stop()` records the stop time in the structure; and `clk_elapsed_us()` calculates the elapsed time between the start and stop times in microseconds.  The package is written to provide me with cross-platform portability (at the cost of some headaches in determining which is the best sub-second timing routine available at compile time).

You can find my code for timers on Github in the repository https://github.com/jleffler/soq, in the `src/libsoq` directory — files `timer.h` and `timer.c`.  The code has not yet caught up with macOS Sierra having `clock_gettime()`, though it could be compiled to use it with `-DHAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME` as a command-line compiler option.

This code was called from a function `one_test()`:

```
static void one_test(int seed)
{
    printf("Seed; %d\n", seed);
    enum { COUNT = 10000000 };
    test_primality_tester("IsPrime1", seed, IsPrime1, COUNT);
    test_primality_tester("IsPrime2", seed, IsPrime2, COUNT);
    test_primality_tester("IsPrime3", seed, IsPrime3, COUNT);
    test_primality_tester("isprime1", seed, isprime1, COUNT);
    test_primality_tester("isprime2", seed, isprime2, COUNT);
    test_primality_tester("isprime3", seed, isprime3, COUNT);
}
```

And the main program can take one or a series of seeds, or uses the current time as a seed:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
            one_test(atoi(argv[i]));
    }
    else
        one_test(time(0));
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this response, it validates my thinking. The example you pointed out in the libsoq directory is clear, but I don't see any setup code for a monotonic clock config. I assume I can just use the COCK_MONOTONIC define instead of CLOCK_REALTIME right?

Comment: You're correct.  Until Sierra, I didn't have a machine where CLOCK_MONOTONIC was an option — I was mostly using `gettimeofday()` — so that wasn't as much of an issue to me.  It is my 'working code'; good enough for my purposes, but not necessarily perfect.  One disadvantage of CLOCK_MONOTONIC is that it doesn't give you an absolute timestamp (relative to The Epoch — aka 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00), whereas `gettimeofday()` does.  But for performance measuring, you're seldom worried about the time it was run to the same level of precision as you're worried about how long it took to run.